# SQL Server stored procedure update record and return value at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion

Thanks in advance;
I inherited a stored procedure that increments a record and returns its value in a single call.  The intent is to only return a single value just like an Identity() column.
Here is the stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetNextKey]
  @RetVal int OUTPUT,
  @Name varchar(250)
AS
  UPDATE Keys
  SET Key_Next = Key_Next + 1,
       @RetVal = Key_Next + 1
  FROM Keys
  WHERE Key_Table = @Name
```

Unfortunately, this is VERY old code and I cannot modify the application to implement Identity(). This has worked in production for years being accessed solely by a ColdFusion application.  It is now being called by a C# application and we're getting what appears to be a threading issue.  I need to solve this in SQL and not in CF or .NET because this procedure is called in a ton of locations in both applications.

They are getting the same values returned as if they live in independent environments.  I should add the fact that it does work as expected most of the time, but not always.  My guess is that it's only under severe load when it's called in the exact same millisecond in each application.

I would hate to do some sort of lock because this thing is called thousands of times per hour.  I'm afraid we'll end up with deadlock issues.

For clarity, here are the calls in CF and C#:

```
<CFFUNCTION name="getNextId" returntype="numeric" access="public">
  <CFARGUMENT name="keyTableName" type="string" required="yes" >
  <CFARGUMENT name="dbSource"     type="string" required="yes" >
  <cfstoredproc procedure="sp_GetNextKey" datasource="#ARGUMENTS.dbSource#" returnCode="No">
    <cfprocparam type="OUT" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER" variable="RetVal">
    <cfprocparam type="IN" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#UCase(ARGUMENTS.keyTableName)#" maxlength="250">
  </cfstoredproc>
  <cfquery name="ab" datasource="#ARGUMENTS.dbSource#">
    SET ARITHABORT ON
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn RetVal >
</CFFUNCTION>
```

C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetNextKey", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var outParam = new SqlParameter("@RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
outParam.Size = 128;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outParam);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = tableName;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//get the return value
retVal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RetVal"].Value);
conn.Close();
```

What is the best approach that would allow this thing to return a unique value for any application calling it?

Based on the comments, we tried this but it did not change the results:

```
ALTER 
PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetNextKey]
  @RetVal int OUTPUT,
  @Name varchar(250)
AS
  UPDATE Keys
  WITH (ROWLOCK)
  SET @RetVal = Key_Next = Key_Next + 1
  FROM Keys
  WHERE Key_Table = @Name
```

Also tried but did not work:
    `ALTER 
    PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetNextKey]
      @RetVal int OUTPUT,
      @Name varchar(250)
    AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXEC sp_getapplock @LockMode = 'Shared', @Resource = 'Keys'; 
        UPDATE Keys
        WITH (ROWLOCK)
        SET @RetVal = Key_Next = Key_Next + 1
        FROM Keys
        WHERE Key_Table = @Name
    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Keys'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION`

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify the application to use identity? You would only be modifying the table in sql server, and could set the seed to the max(Key) value. Or, perhaps you want to look into NEWID(), but either way i'm confused as to why the application would be modified. I'm also guessing Keys doesn't have a unique constraint on it?

Comment: Look into isolation levels and ROWLOCK.

Comment: The proc shouldn't have a concurrency issue but could be refactored as `SET @RetVal = Key_Next = Key_Next + 1`. Importantly, the `KeyTable` should be the primary key.

Comment: Maybe you could implement a sequence instead of a Keys table. Then you just change your procedure to increment the sequence and return you the value. Similar to what you are doing but a little more robust using a sequence.

Comment: `outparam.Size = 128;` looks wrong and can probably just be removed.

Comment: Based only on what you've shown, I think you're trying to put a band-aid on an amputated limb.

Comment: ROWLOCK looks promising.  Should I worry about deadlocks or SQL Server doing an automatic lock escalation based on lock thresholds?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: Are you incrementing Key_Next to make it act like a row version number? The answers won't give you a "unique" number, but just increment the row's Key_Next. With this code, Key_Table='foo' and Key_Table='bar' can still have the same Key_Next.

Comment: @Shawn the version of SQL Server is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)

Comment: Key_Next is just an integer that is used as a primary key in the Key_Table where the Key_Table can be anything like "Orders", "Products", and other various tables.

Comment: What about using:
  `EXEC sp_getapplock @LockMode = 'Shared', @Resource = 'Keys';` 

Will that do what we expect or will the 'Shared' mode perform just the same?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetNextKey]
  @RetVal int OUTPUT,
  @Name varchar(250)
AS
  BEGIN TRAN
      SELECT @RetVal = MAX(Key_Next) + 1 FROM Keys WHERE Key_Table = @Name
      UPDATE Keys SET Key_Next = @RetVal WHERE Key_Table = @Name
  COMMIT
```

This intentionally split the two operations into separate statements, and wraps them in a transaction such that the correct locks should be used and consistency maintained.

Comment: How does this handle concurrency issues any differently than the original code?   Stored procs already implicitly run in their own transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetNextKey]
  @RetVal int OUTPUT,
  @Name varchar(250)
AS
  UPDATE Keys
  SET @RetVal = Key_Next = Key_Next + 1
  FROM Keys
  WHERE Key_Table = @Name
```

You need to set the value of the variable at the same time that you update the field.

Comment: How is this different than the problematic code posted in the question?

Comment: In the code, you are trying to set the variable value like when you do on the select statement, but when you are updating the field, you need to update the variable at the same time the database field is updated.

Comment: I didn't realize that SET elements didn't all happen at the same time, like a SELECT. That's kinda cool.

Answer (score 0):

Coldfusion concurrency bug in function:

If the component holding the ColdFusion getNextId function is cached in memory, then it could be causing your problem because the default scope for non-explicitly scoped variables, such as your RetVal variable, is at the component level, not the function as one unfamiliar with CF might assume, making it global to the component.  Add the following line just after the arguments in the function to make it no longer susceptible to concurrency issues (defines the variable to be local to the function.)

`<cfset var RetVal />`

Or, you can explicitly scope the variable to the function by prefixing it with `local.` everyhwere it appears in the function.  Ex: `local.RetVal`. (works in CF9+)